# How to find if Joomla SEF is on or not

Tags: php, joomla, sef

I need to find if Joomla's SEF is enabled or not.

To make things worse, Joomla has different SEF mechanisms ([see here](http://docs.joomla.org/SEF_URLs_in_Joomla!_1.5) for more info).

The function I need to fill in is simple:

```
function rewrite_enabled(){
    return (boolean)$something; // typecast is frivolous
}
```

The only idea I have so far is:

```
function rewrite_enabled(){
    $url='index.php?option=com_xyz';
    return JRoute($url)!=$url;
}
```

Maybe normalizing both URLs (lowercase or by get vars) might make the function a little bit more effective, though it sounds like a big hack, with serious repercussions.

Of course, searched for an answer on Joomla Docs, StackOverflow and Google, without any success. I also inspected Joomla's runtime internals, and but nothing came up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using Joomla's Core SEF System you could get yourself the config and check if SEF is set to true.

```
$conf = &JFactory::getConfig();
echo ' SEF is:  '.(($conf->sef == 1) ? 'on' : 'off');
```

(not tested)

Hope it helps a bit.
Cheers

For Joomla 3.x you will need:

```
$conf = &JFactory::getConfig();
echo ' SEF is:  '.(($conf->get('sef') == 1) ? 'on' : 'off');
```

Comment: I'd like to ask the same thing as I asked ircmaxell.

Comment: Erm, this is the setting for Joomla's Core SEF system. Some of the other SEF Components need this to be set to '1', some of them not. You might need fallback's such as checking the database for installed extensions, filter the SEF extensions, and get their config files. there is now general way AFAIK.

Answer (score 4):

Just call:  [`JFactory::getConfig()`](http://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getConfig):

```
return (boolean) JFactory::getConfig()->getValue('config.sef', false);
```

Comment: Thanks, but how does that check the other various SEF configs? Or is this sorta of a master SEF config?

Comment: @Christian: Any **good** extension will use the core sef setting and override the router in other areas.  And this value is the master on-off switch for the core.  The other settings just determine how sef behaves...

Comment: I marked david's as the answer to give him some SO motivation(points) ;) gave you +1 for the answer, though. Thanks ircmaxell

Answer (score 2):

Well, uh, this is embarasing...

I was looking at some old code of mine and found the following:

```
$sef = JFactory::getApplication()->getRouter()->getMode()
```

It does seem to do what I want, though I'm not sure which one's better...

Meh, now it's official, a week into any project, and I forget all about my own code :D